# Good clock and weather widget for someone dealing with multiple timezones / cities

Tags: app-widgets, clock, weather

I work for a big corporate with development centers around the world. There are 4 in particular that I interact with frequently and travel to regularly.

What I'd like is a clock and weather widget with the following features:

- Can have multiple instances set to different cities.
- Shows the city it is set to.
- Can fit 4 on a page, so 2x2 or 4x1.
- Shows time (for dealing with meetings)
- Graphical indicator of day night (for a quick are they likely to be awake check)
- Shows local weather (for small talk on phone calls)
- Including highs and lows (in case I have to go there tomorrow)
- In Celsius (because I'm not American)

The Beautiful Widgets "Beautiful Smaller Home Weather" is visually spot on what I'm after, but you can't have multiple instances.

Is there another widget out there that meets my requirements?

Comment: I like questions like this because they are specific. And they give budding developers some great ideas about apps that are in real demand!

Answer (score 6):

Hey tolomea. I couldn't find a widget that could do all that but I did find this app that can.

> World Watch is an advanced world clock for an editable list of locations around the world. Includes sunrise, sunset, dawn and dusk times for the current or a given calendar date. Also includes weather conditions and a 4-day forecast.

I haven't used it since it's a paid app but looking at the description and the screenshots it looks like it can do everything you've asked for. I don't believe it's a widget but having a single icon on your home screen to launch it would be just as easy as having widgets.

[World Watch](http://www.appbrain.com/app/world-watch/tinyappworks.worldwatch#)

[image: World Watch QR Code]

Answer (score 1):

I'm favoriting this question.  I just installed diviClock widget this morning--http://www.appbrain.com/app/diviclock/divi.clock.  it doesn't tick all of your boxes, but it has a 1x1 widget option (which I wanted and saves a great deal of space) plus the date (also something I wanted), and you can have multiple instances for your different time zones.
[image]